# How to make a BufferedReader yield?

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedreader

Let's say I've got two threads running. Thread #1 reads System.in like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String s;
while (true) {
    s=br.readLine();
    if(s!=null)
        doSomethingWithThat(s);
    }
}
```

I also have `Thread #2` that performs some operations, among others needs to read `System.in` when certain things happens (that in general are not triggered by `Thread #1`.)

Is it possible to somehow interrupt `Thread #1` so that `br.readLine()` would `return null` and `#Thread #2` could read `System.in`?

Comment: It's a better idea to have a single thread handle the reading instead of trying to switch between threads. You probably have a design issue here.

Comment: In general yeah, but this is about 2 different components that don't play along nicely and absolutely must a) be in separate threads and b) both be able to read System.in

Comment: Real life case being that thread #1 reads console for user input and # thread  #2 asks for logins etc missing data when no GUI is present. These components usually run in different programs.

Comment: Okay Seppo, I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 0):

Added this before readLine() & did the trick

```
while(System.in.available()<=0 || yield)
    Sleep.millis(420);
```